# How to share notes in Ubuntu one?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sharing, notes

Is it possible to share notes over Ubuntu One with a public link like in Google Docs? I found a solution [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/26817/) but it does not work anymore. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, sharing notes in Ubuntu One is not possible. The link you posted in your question shows that it is [an idea under consideration](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/26817/) and may or may not be actually implemented.

If you really have to share your notes, then copy the contents of the notes and save it as a .txt file and share it on Ubuntu One.